# How to monitor number of open connections in wildfly?

Tags: console, database-connection, wildfly, monitoring

I'm using wildfly version 10.1.0.Final. I tried to figure out how to monitor open datasource connections so 
1) i have a data source configured with statistics enabled. it has a pool max of 250
2) i created code that when invoked, it loops and obtains 1000 connections from the datasource (it obtains 100 then pauses for 10 seconds etc'. All obtained
connections are saved in an array. I then close the connections, in a similar manner (100 at a time, with 10 seconds delay)

3) when i start the application, it shows 9 out of 250 connections are used for that datasource. (Both Active and Max used)

when i invoke the above code, i continuously hit the Refresh results link in the console but the above two counts (Active and Max Used) remain at 9.
i also examined the obtained connections and they are different from each other.

Why is the count not changing as more and more connections are obtained?